# Can I make the UIBarButton Item in a nav bar look like a Back button?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have an app that has a `UIViewController` with a navigation bar up top.  The nav bar has a `UIBarButton` on it, which is rounded rectangle.  Can I make it look like a Back button of a `UINavigationBar`?

Comment: Sure. `navBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem = button;`

Comment: Hmm..I created the outlet for it `@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *button;
` but it didnt work, xcode complains because what i have is a uibarbuttonitem. Should I change the control to uibarbuttonitem or vv?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You should not make the nav bar into a bar button item, instead you modify one of its properties.

Comment: I want the UIBarButtonItem to look like a navBar back button, the one that has a straight edge on the right but a pointy triangle tip on the left edge.

Comment: @H2CO3: Is there a way to make it look like that?

Comment: See my very first comment here.

Comment: It didnt work.  I created the property for the navbar and uibarbuttonitem and connected the outlets but i still get the same rectangular button